# compare array and remove element

Tags: php, arrays

**i have a array of values**

```
(array 1)
array:22 [▼
  0 => 1
  1 => 2
  2 => 3
  4 => 5
  5 => 8
  6 => 9
  7 => 10
  8 => 11
  9 => 12
  10 => 15
  11 => 16
  12 => 17
  13 => 18
  14 => 19
  15 => 22
  16 => 23
  17 => 24
  18 => 25
  19 => 26
  20 => 29
  21 => 30
  22 => 31
]
```

**and another array of values like**

```
(array 2)
[0=>01
1=>02
2=>03
3=>04
......
]
```

**i want to match the first array 
with second array and if the values matches remove that (key=>value) from first array**

Comment: have you bothered to look at [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)?

Comment: Have you even made an attempt to do anything? Post your code so far.

Comment: I was looking for 'Possible duplicate of - what have you tried so far'

Comment: And note that the sequence `01`, `02`, `03`, `04`, etc gets quite interesting when you get to `08` and `09`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

array_diff() is suitable for your requirement